# Dissatisfaction towards/with/to?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, prepositions

If I have some complaints about someone, should I use “dissatisfaction towards/with/to”?

I have looked at the usage [here](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/dissatisfaction), and I see so many versions and am wondering if there’s any difference?

Comment: The examples in the link are actually good. There are *NO* examples of *dissatisfaction towards*, so where did Joshua's confusion stem from, I have little idea.  And only two examples for *dissatisfaction to* i.e. *“But his measures speedily* ***gave dissatisfaction to*** *the Argentine or Creole party,”*. The meaning is clearly different from that of "with"It is ungrammatical to say **…gave dissatisfaction with…** -1

Comment: It would have made a much better question if the expressions "*dissatisfaction among*" and "*dissatisfaction by/of*" had been included.

Comment: There is also about.  Yes, they are all slightly different. For a complaint: **express dissatisfaction about a person**.  about often means regarding the subject of. talk about a problem.

Answer (score 6):

"Dissatisfaction with" implies specific responsibility - i.e. I am unhappy with the response by THAT person. "Dissatisfaction towards" implies lessened responsibility - i.e. I am unhappy with the outcome which may have resulted from that person's involvement (or maybe from another factor). "Dissatisfaction to" means that the recipient was dissatisfied - i.e. "My failure to pay resulted in dissatisfaction to my landlord."

Answer (score 1):

**One can answer your question easily, if they unlock the meaning and usage of to, towards and with.**

While, all (with, to and towards) prepositions are acceptable here.

Let's consider the preposition "with."

The preposition "with" has [10 senses](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with) in English Oxford Living Dictionaries, from which, the sense No. 4 is:

> **4.** in opposition to.

Thus when I say:

> - John has dissatisfaction **with** his brothers.

I meant it that John had dissatisfaction **in opposition to** his brothers.

---

Dissatisfaction "to" or "towards"?

When I say

> "John has dissatisfaction to ...,"

that means that John has dissatisfaction, purposefully (=with a full, strong purpose).

And when I say

> "John has dissatisfaction towards ...,"

that means that John has dissatisfaction purposely (=with a purpose being neither full nor strong).

Hence, in such contexts, "to" is stronger than "towards."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this use of "dissatisfaction" - the more direct way to express this would be "to be dissatisfied" - a less convoluted way to get the idea across.